# Retrieve Regeistered users info - asp website

Tags: asp.net

i have created an intranet website using visual studio(c#) , i have published it as well and it works fine . the website has a registration page and lets user to create accounts , my problem is whenever someone registers in website , i would like to see the list of registered users and assign them permissions(member , guest , admin etc) so that not everyone who register can see the protected content

how do i do this , do i use visual studio's ASP.NET CONFIGURATION PAGE for this?

am a complete beginner in asp , can some one please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using roles in .Net. When a new user is created just have them have a default role of guest. Then you can create a notification that gets triggered by a new user registration such as an email, then you can review the list of users and edit a user to have a specific role.

Documentation can be found here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k850zwb(v=vs.100).aspx